# Is there any LaTeX package for drawing Gantt diagrams?

Tags: latex, gantt-chart

Are there LaTeX packages for (more or less) easily drawing Gantt diagrams?

Thanks.

Comment: Can this one be migrated to tex.stackexchange? (Like [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25457/5645))

Comment: Also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63877/gantt-chart-package/63915#63915

Answer (score 13):

The [pgfgantt](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt) package is quite easy to use and does linking.

Answer (score 8):

I have not used myself, but it looks like PSTricks offers some Gantt chart drawing capabilities.

Main PSTricks site: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi

Example of Gantt chart using PSTricks: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Charts/gantt

Answer (score 3):

There is the [pst-gantt package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-gantt/). The bad news is, that you have to draw dependencies between the tasks yourself. So you need to use the `\psline` macro to draw lines and arrows.