# Which Gantt chart/Project management tool would you recommend for linux?

Tags: linux, project-management, charts, gantt-chart

I need a Project management tool that works in Linux, and has Gantt charts.

1. It doesn't have to be free, just not expensive.
2. I don't care how it stores the information I give it, as long as I can access it.
3. I must be able to **print** the Gantt charts.
4. Must work in Linux.

With those requirements, what can you recommend?

TheObserver asked a windows specific version of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151787/recommended-chartingreportingdashboard-tool).

Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Planner](http://live.gnome.org/Planner), and [OpenSched](http://opensched.sourceforge.net/), in that order.  There are some decent online Gantt (this is the correct spelling) chart tools online as well, usually integrated within a project management or bug-tracking web app or software package.

Answer (score 15):

I use [TaskJuggler](http://www.taskjuggler.org/) - it's more powerful than other OSS software I've tried, but it's very complicated. It's the only software I found that could do what I needed, but I still consider it to be "best of a bad bunch". I too wouldn't mind paying, if I could be sure the software would do everything I needed.

The big flaw with planner seems to be around resource leveling/allocation but I admit I haven't looked deeply into it. Planner would be my second choice.

Comment: Thanks, TaskJuggler seems to do the job well. I would consider the way you describe project - in clean, concise and modular set of plain text documents - a big advantage. Fits nicely into version control and build scripts. Scheduling works well, reports are nicely customizable. And it's not that difficult, one afternoon was enough to learn the basic features and I find them quite intuitive. OTOH, resource allocation issue in Planner has been around since 2004 and hasn't been solved yet. In my case it makes Planner useless.

Answer (score 10):

[Ganttproject](http://ganttproject.biz/) is written in java and works on every platform.

Comment: Be wary, this doesn't allow you to take off-periods or holidays into account when allocating resources. Makes it a no deal for me.

Comment: i use this one as it has good support for dependencies (ie one task starting when another finishes)

Comment: My intention was to use if for personal planning. It suits my needs pretty good.

Answer (score 5):

You could try http://live.gnome.org/Planner maybe it satisfy your needs. :)

Answer (score 3):

The answers to [[Is there any LaTeX package for drawing Gantt diagrams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171809/is-there-any-latex-package-for-drawing-gantt-diagrams)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171809/is-there-any-latex-package-for-drawing-gantt-diagrams). may be viable.

Comment: Interesting. Is "gantt" the proper spelling? If so, that would explain why I didn't find that question.

Comment: [Wikipedia says yes!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart)

Answer (score 3):

You could also try some of the web-based project management tools. These days they fare quite well to the desktop alternatives. I can recommend [dotProject](http://dotproject.net/). It's a nice, easy to use tool and it has printable gantt charts.

Comment: Although I like and use dotProject, it has issues with Gantt Charts when the project gets above a certain level of complexity (it just fails to generate them).

Comment: You can increase the memory allowed in PHP (System Configuration has a setting to set how much memory to use for gantt chart generation) and it should be fine after that.

Answer (score 3):

Also check [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/).